# Is it possible to get the keys from a union of objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

Simplest example

assuming this type

```
type Foo = { a: number } | { b: string } | { c: boolean };
```

is it possible to get

```
type KeysOfFoo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
type Failed = keyof Foo; // never
```

[TsPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJygF8oAfNKYnAZ2DIEtcBzK2+gYxzEEAGwgZcVAFCTQkTMigBrCCDgAzWAigB6bXjiRJQA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like `keyof (A | B | C)` will result in only the keys that are *definitely* on an object of type `A | B | C`, meaning it would have to be a key known to be in *all* of `A`, `B`, and `C`, which is: `keyof A & keyof B & keyof C`.  That is, `keyof T` is  "[contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in `T`".
This isn't what you want though (in your case there are no keys in common so the intersection is `never`).

If you're looking for the set of keys which are in *at least one* of the members of your union, you need to *distribute* the `keyof` operator over the union members.  Luckily there is a way to do this via [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  It looks like this:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
```

The `T extends any` doesn't do much in terms of type checking, but it does signal to the compiler that operations on `T` should happen for each union member of `T` separately and then the results would be united back together into a union.  That means `AllKeys<A | B | C>` will be treated like `AllKeys<A> | AllKeys<B> | AllKeys<C>`.  Let's try it:

```
type KeysOfFoo = AllKeys<Foo>;
// type KeysOfFoo = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Looks good!  Please note that you should be careful about actually using `KeysOfFoo` in concert with objects of type `Foo`. `keyof` is contravariant for a reason:

```
function hmm(foo: Foo, k: AllKeys<Foo>) {
  foo[k]; // error!
  // "a" | "b" | "c"' can't be used to index type 'Foo'.
  // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Foo'
}
```

It's not safe to index into `foo` with `k` for the same reason you can't safely index into a value of type `{a: number}` with `"b"`... the key might not exist on the object.  Obviously you know your use cases better than I do though, so you may well have some legitimate use of `AllKeys<Foo>` and `Foo` together.  I'm just saying to be careful.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCGFIUA-FANYoD2AZoVAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AsACg5oSFET5YCZGnQBveoNTBxASwoBzADRQARoIoBXALaWJUAL5QAPlB0BjQZc6ccBAMFlSCACJ05K7YMrIA9PFQitAqBABEdOkeUOmW2Z7p3gW5VOlyCuDQAGIBqjp0Ng5O4q45OtZQ+kambZ4+fgFBDK5xlUoaqADy3LWcqvBIKBhzsXKJyVXKyzNzqpkleYfFFbLcthTewIacFFAAFvb2ABTcAYJzFmyCi5PoqwBKLxyKBQN6cADabAAupIoBsJOJOOIAIQg+FJA45I7Y4oAcig3gYeOAVmgtlQECoyXmxiopE2SjxczxADp0RsAApIyDiUBQPF0AlUTgQWgUTik0iGfRQW6M6DMgIEuQuIA)

Comment: Thanks~! can't believe it was that simple

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score 0):

`Failed` is of type `never` because your `Foo` type can't have any keys. It's currently set up as an intersection type between 3 completely exclusive types, so there are no valid keys.

If you change from using `|` to a `&`, then it'll work as is.

```
type Foo = { a: number } & { b: string } & { c: boolean }

type a = keyof Foo // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJygF8oAyNKYnAZ2DIEtcBzK2+gYxzEEAGwgZcVAFCTQkTMigBrCCDgAzWAigB6bXjiRJQA)

Comment: Note that `|` is a union, not an intersection.  And the three types are not *exclusive*; they just don't share any declared properties.  `{a: number}` and `{a: string}` would be exclusive because you can't have an object that satisfies both types.