# How can I merge types back in TypeScript without touching the original types

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following types:

```js
type A = {
    role: 'admin',
    force?: boolean
}

type B = {
    role: 'regular',
}

type Or = A | B;
```

I want to be able to do:

```js
const or = {
    role: 'regular'
} as Or;

const {role, force} = or;
```

without getting the error:

```
Property 'force' does not exist on type 'Or'.(2339)
```

and **without using Touching `A` and `B`**

I tried to do:

```js
type Merge<Obj> = {
    [k in keyof Obj]: Obj[k]
}

const {role, force} = or as Merge<Or>;
```

but same error

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMjcZOnQA8pgVwAPnIDckjtloBnYFHYLUGLELUadegZMYlCkzlDm9sbg0ACyEJiaEAA8pnwAVgB8nkpQANoA1lB0UAUQINgsERkAukRp6YU1RiiOLm5IKhAMUGycECGIHmFQ8Ykp5pn2QA)

Comment: @about14sheep as I wrote I want without

Comment: Some reference, and possibly duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496154/accessing-different-properties-in-a-typescript-union-type

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK9xgN) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: YES @jcalz ! can you write an answer and I will set it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript object types aren't *sealed* or *exact* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  Just because a type doesn't mention a property, it doesn't *prohibit* the property.  So technically speaking a value of type `{role: "regular"}` might have a property called `force` of some completely unknown type:

```
type A = { role: 'admin', force?: boolean };
type B = { role: 'regular' };
type Or = A | B;

const hmm = { role: 'regular', force: 9000 } as const;
const oops: Or = hmm; // <-- accepted
```

And by that logic is not safe for you to do what you're trying to do.  The only *safe* destructuring of a value of type `Or` into its pieces would make the `force` property of type `unknown`.

But from here forward, let's assume that issue is not going to arise, and that we assert that the value only has properties known by the compiler, and any properties not mentioned in the type will be of type `undefined`.

---

How then can we "fix" a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `Or` to be a version that explicitly knows about all keys from the other members so that the compiler lets you index into it with any of these keys?

Here's one possible way:

```
type FixUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never> =
    T extends unknown ? (
        T & { [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never } extends infer O ? {
            [P in keyof O]: O[P]
        } : never
    ) : never
```

First let's make sure it works on `Or`:

```
type FixedOr = FixUnion<Or>;
/* type FixedOr  = {
    role: 'admin';
    force?: boolean | undefined;
} | {
    role: 'regular';
    force?: undefined;
} */
```

That looks correct.  Both union members have a `role` and a `force` property.  The first member is the same as `A`, while the second member is `B` with an additional [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of type `undefined`.  So now you're allowed to destructure it:

```
const { role, force } = or as FixUnion<Or>;
// const role: "admin" | "regular"
// const force: boolean | undefined
```

---

So how does it work?  First let's look at the `K` type parameter.  I'm actually just using a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) value to compute all the keys of every member of the `T` union.  The type `T extends unknown ? keyof T : never` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which breaks `T` into its union members, grabs their individual keys, and unites them back together into a new union.  I sometimes call this operation `AllKeys<T>` as shown in [Is it possible to get the keys from a union of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61685168/2887218) .  For `Or`, `K` will be `"role" | "force"`.

So now `K` is all the keys.  The body of `FixUnion<T>` is another distributive conditional type; for each member of the `T` union, we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with `{ [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never }`.  That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with all optional keys (hence the `?`) which are present in `K` but not in the current union member (using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)).  And the property values [are `never`, the impossible type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  For `Or`, the first member will look like `A & {}` and the second member will look like `B & { force?: never }`.  Note that optional properties automatically get `undefined` in their domain, so it's the same as `B & { force?: undefined }`.  The point is that the `force` property in the second union member is known to be either missing or `undefined`.

Finally, in order to make things prettier, I use a technique to turn intersections like `A & {}` into a plain object like `{role: "admin", force?: boolean}`, as described in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) ; the `... extends infer O ? {[P in keyof O]: O[P]} : never}` does that.  So then the first member becomes `{role: "admin", force?: boolean}`, and the second becomes `{role: "regular", force?: undefined}`.

---

Let's just test it out on a different union, just to see how it works:

```
type Foo = FixUnion<{ a: 0 } | { b: 1 } | { a: 2 } | { c: 3 }>;
/* type Foo = {
    a: 0;
    b?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    b: 1;
    a?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    a: 2;
    b?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
} | {
    c: 3;
    a?: undefined;
    b?: undefined;
} */
```

All four union members have all three keys, but at least two keys are optional keys of type `undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMjcZOnQA8pgVwAPnIDckjtloBnYFHYLUGLELUadegZMYlCkzlDm9iiOLm4AFpSUnj6qJP66+oxQbJyEUACcAAzFUCFhUDGu9pVugmDOROYKCZS2UAD07VAAPAC0vaEcXGDAEOSSUuDQAGLUAB4AqrTUTt0AKgxQANJQEHOjtOThAAo4kJigWxAgCmu7+xCH4dq0ANa02ADutFDcUK-XbAsKB3Ii0CAANwgmAAfAglCD7gcjlAXu8vj8-gAKBHeO4AMmQUAA2scoHQoABROYcXDacgQbpbTYAkBAkEwgC6vCg4KhFhCe2R4ToLGhEV+im80owpPJP1Z7NMnMapM5uIwITBkOhCIAlFBtfyJpMZLM5mMmohzUsVrRuuYYfZ2gAqKAmKDmy0WTwIlR5MhUOjEezeHJcHkCIQiKA2F4Mlh0Mb2EI2LwYf1+LQZAyh1jsCNEeMQRPg8gpqAu9oOJyuIn+zbh6AhRAeco25arR3Oro1FJ5ABEFBotAHsagA-SgQHKE6FVrbib-EE+BjccOJaT41NM0ECg7du6SFCREKpXHx74RAAjOe0yeoAAmO9EjhEADMpSds7dHume8QdN0FIU883QPgeWLUtkwRDhII3aDy3EC8ESvKBrzA0J4ITLdMLgosENw5C0wRECn0wiCCJwss8OwzcaOIqUMDfKB30w0g6MQijOKIkIqyAA)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access properties of a union type that only some members of that union type have.

You're getting the same error, and for the same reason is this simplified code:

```
type A = {
    role: 'admin',
    force?: boolean
}

type B = {
    role: 'regular',
}

const obj: A | B =
    Math.random() > 0.5 ?
        { role: 'admin', force: true } :
        { role: 'regular' }

obj.force // type error
```

If you want that property, then you have to prove that it exists first which narrows your union to just the values that that property.

```
if ('force' in obj) obj.force // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMjcZI7ZaAZ2BRsfAFZE4AHzkIlUALKlgACwB0mEeTYlAAUAJRQAHxQAAw+AKxQ3K4YyFhCahQ09AxQbJyEUMCY2tBiUATJGEhpqiQaOnoGUBIo1jY+eVxQAPTdUNrmpCzQYDiQmKBQpBxcZmaS1CxQwcSdEMRQdFa24W0d7F29UGZDEChAA)

---

You can add the same thing to your playground in order to make typechecking pass.

```
const mergedOr = or as Merge<Or>;
const force = 'force' in or && or.force; // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCcD2AbCAXFAOQCGAJgLYCWAdsQDRoYBm2mAxhAPxEBG2PBFK0UAXxQpQkKACEEyZuhz4ixTBADmAV1ylMjcZOnQA8pgVwAPnIDckjtloBnYFHYLUGLELUadegZMYlCkzlDm9sbg0ACyEJiaEAA8pnwAVgB8nkpQANoA1lB0UAUQINgsERkAukRp6YU1RiiOLm6UCUnk5goeYVDxiSnmmfZtrlBsnNCIxNNcxMW07hYAZGurAHQLEChAA)

---

It's also worth mentioning that this type:

```
type Merge<Obj> = {
    [k in keyof Obj]: Obj[k]
}
```

Does nothing useful. It maps an object types keys to the value types for those keys, which will *exactly* the same as the input type. So whatever you think this is supposed to do, it's not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

use the `Pick` utility to achieve that and here is my solution you might consider helpful:

```
type A = {
    role: 'admin',
    force?: boolean
}

type B = {
    role: 'regular',
}
type Or = Pick<A & B, 'force' | 'role'>;
const or = {
    role: 'regular'
} as Or;

const {role, force} = or;
```

Answer (score 0):

Redneck hack:

`const {role, force} = or as any;`

But seriously, you can't. Typescript is helping you out here. If you had done this, it would work:

```js
const or: Or =
    role: 'admin'
};

const {role, force} = or;
```

This way the compiler matches it to the type A, which at least has a chance of having `force`, so force here is type `boolean | undefined`

Comment: as you see in the correct answer, it's possible